# TensorFlow shape checker

Tags: tensorflow

Unlike most programming languages, TensorFlow does not regard the shape of an array as part of the type. The downside of this is that, if you make a mistake and accidentally provide data of the wrong shape, it may silently give a wrong answer e.g. [Slightly different shape converges to wrong number - why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47417671/slightly-different-shape-converges-to-wrong-number-why) which makes debugging difficult.

Does there exist a shape checker for TF? That is, a function or program that can analyze a graph (with sample `feed_dict` if need be) and raise the alarm if there is a shape mismatch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tensorflow does offer a shape checker mechanism which is technically the shape argument you should specify while declaring Tensorflow place holders. By default, tensorflow takes [None,None] for shape. But , for example if you do specify the shape while declaring your place holders, then it will raise shape error whenever user enters data of incorrect/conflicting shape. For example
lets say I declared a place holder named X and did specify its shape argument too:

```
X=tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[None,256])
```

Now, this means that number of rows of X can vary but number of features will always be 256. And now , if I mistakenly feed data of shape lets say 1000 rows and 20 features, shape error will be raised.

Also, check this link :https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/placeholder

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
print(str(tf.Shape(test_tensor))) # where test_tensor is
                                whatever your tensor's name is
```

Documentation available here: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/shape